# BibLatex doesn´t show Referencelist

Tags: biblatex, texmaker

For an assignment I have to use LaTeX and `biblatex`. I am using it with Texmaker.

I defined an external .bib file where I put my references.

So, my problem is when I am running (pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex 
It often doesn´t show me the cited references. Instead of the defined style, the citations in the text are shown as the shortcut:

Example:

```
@MISC{main,
  AUTHOR = "asdf",
  TITLE = "adsf",
  HOWPUBLISHED = "adsf",
  YEAR="4544"
}
@MISC{ev,.....
```

In the .tex file:

```
\cite{main}
```

This is compiled as [1] and shown in the Referencelist. But when I use any other cite:

```
\cite{ev}
```

It´s shown as [ev] and not in the Referencelist.

Furthermore: Some shortcuts in the literature file are highlighted in black and others are red (same color as the options (author, title, etc)).
And if I want to use `\cite` in the .tex file the black shortcuts are highlighted from Texmaker and the others aren´t.

Sometimes the output says that the library is empty, sometimes it doesn´t...
But it always says to rerun biber on the (biblatex) texfile (biblatex). Thought I tried that, nothing has changed.

If I run bibTex on the bib file it says:

```
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'literatur.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

In texmaker I configured Bib(La)tex as biber %.bcf

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=numeric,   
            isbn=false,               
            pagetracker=true,        
            maxbibnames=50,           
            maxcitenames=3,           
            autocite=inline,        
            block=space,               
            backref=true,              
            backrefstyle=three+,     
            date=short]{biblatex}
```

Comment: You have to compile the bibliography with `biber` instead of `bibtex`. If you want to use `bibtex` as the engine for the bibliography, you have to use `backend=bibtex` instead of `backend=biber`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! So your main file is called `literatur.tex`, correct? After you run `pdflatex`, does `literatur.bcf` exist? `biber` thinks it does not so the first thing to figure out is if the problem is that the file isn't created or if the problem is that `biber` is not able to find it. If the file is not created, look for errors when running `pdflatex` - either on the console or in the `.log`. If the file is created but `biber` can't find it, try running `biber literatur` from the command line in your working directory (where your `.tex` file is).

Comment: I assume you more or less followed the instructions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) (just for future reference). (Some people prefer to leave out the file extension in this cases and let Biber figure them out for itself, thus in this post it is only `biber %`, not `biber %.bcf`.) Could it be that you have enabled one of those "move temporary files to a temp directory" options?

Comment: @guido,I have no clue of Latex, so I don´t knew the difference, I just want that it works....

Comment: @crf, My Mainfile is sem.tex and my library literature.bib, when I run compile all (pdflatex -> bibtex -> 2x Pdflatex->show pdf) it generates an bcf from my tex, yes.@ moewe, I had the whole time biber %, but in some Forum, it was suggested to add the .bcf, because it could save that Problem. And yes, in my Bib(La)Tex Field I reference to the directory where miktex is installed and there to biber.exe